# How to return the users age from their year of birth

Tags: javascript, date, object

These are the criteria for the question;

1. return the user's age as a number.
2. you can assume that the passed user will always have a 'yearOfBirth' property.

my answer was;

```
function getUserAge (user) {
    const year = new Date().getFullYear()
    return year - user.yearOfBirth
}
```

I am unsure to why this does not return the users age. Does anyone have any advice?

my answer is tested against this

```
describe("getUserAge", () => {
    it("returns the age of the passed user based on its yearOfBirth property", () => {
        const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        const user = {
            yearOfBirth: 1989
        };
        expect(getUserAge(user)).to.equal(currentYear - 1989);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you add how the function is called? As in, a [mcve]?

Comment: because you need day, month, year to really calculate the age.

Comment: Regardless of the accuracy of the calculation, it works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1uoc67hz/ What exactly are you getting as result?

Comment: I agree, this should work for the given test even though the calculation is incorrect (since the test doesn't verify correct age calculation either).

Comment: Voting to close as questions on “why isn’t this code working” should have enough code **in the question** to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow for whether the user has had their birthday yet this year. Your current implementation returns the same value in January and December for someone born in June, but of course, the December value should be one higher than the January value.

If all you have to work from is `yearOfBirth`, you cannot accurately return their age. You need the month and day as well. (Depending on how pedantic you want to be, also the hour, minute, and second; but most people aren't that pedantic.)

Comment: This is generally true, but the test will fail if you calculate the age correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the difference between timestamp of the date birth and now.

```
var date_birth= new Date("2010/11/3");
var timestamp_birth= date_birth.getTime();
var now= Date.now();

var diffTimestamp= now - timestamp_birth;
  // ms to secend / second to minute / minute to hour / hour to days of year
console.log( diffTimestamp/1000/60/60/24/365 );
```

*as you can see, knowing only the year is not enough